# Finding highest variable and displaying

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I would like to know how to find the highest variable without using math.max. My aim of my code is to ask the user questions their gaming. The user will enter their gaming hours each day and then it will total all hours, average them and then display most amount of gaming on such days. **I am new to programming, any help is good!**

Here is my code so far...

```js
function total() {
  var th = Number(monday.value) + Number(tuesday.value) + Number(wednesday.value) + Number(thursday.value) + Number(friday.value) + Number(saturday.value) + Number(sunday.value);
  alert("You gamed for " + th + " hours this week");



  var ah = th / 7;
  alert("Your average is " + ah + " hours this week");
}



button.onclick = total;
```

```css
\
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="draft.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<title>The Gaming Hours Quiz</title>

<body>
  <h1>The Gaming Hours Quiz</h1>
</body>
<p>Welcome to the Gaming Hours Quiz. Please fill out the neccesary information correctly to get your true results</p>

<h3 id="nametitle">What is your name?</h3>
<input id="name" type="letter" name="" value="type name here...">

<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Monday?</h3>
<input id="monday" type="number" name="" value="0">


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Tuesday?</h3>
<input id="tuesday" type="number" name="" value="0">


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Wednesday?</h3>
<input id="wednesday" type="number" name="" value="0">


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Thursday?</h3>
<input id="thursday" type="number" name="" value="0">


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Friday?</h3>
<input id="friday" type="number" name="" value="0">


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Saturday?</h3>
<input id="saturday" type="number" name="" value="0">


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Sunday?</h3>
<input id="sunday" type="number" name="" value="0">
<br>
<br>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Why dont' you want to use Math.max?

Comment: @miyamoto, it's probably homework

Comment: Yes it is homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign all the days in an array.

```
var arr = [Number(monday.value), Number(tuesday.value), Number(wednesday.value), Number(thursday.value), Number(friday.value), Number(saturday.value), Number(sunday.value)];
```

Make a `max` variable that will store the maximum value of hours that one "gamed" in one day.

```
var hh = 0;
var max = arr[0];
```

Loop through the array to find the biggest value. If a the previous index has a smaller value than the current index, assign current index to `max`.

```
for(var i = 1;i < arr.length;i++) {
if(arr[i-1] < arr[i]) {
max = arr[i];
  }
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34fbwd6p/) for you.

Answer (score 2):

Let's store all the days in an array:

```
var days = [ parseInt(monday), parseInt(tuesday), parseInt(wednesday), parseInt(thursday), parseInt(friday), parseInt(saturday), parseInt(sunday) ];
```

You can find then find the max value by first establishing a base `max` value (0). You then iterate over each day, and if it's value is more than the `max` value, assign this value to `max`:

```
var max = 0;
days.forEach(function(day) {
    if(day.value > max) {
        max = day.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: They should use `Number(monday.value)` or `parseInt(monday.value)` assuming `monday` is an element. `monday.value` will be a string so adding together two strings will result in concatenation (`'2' + '2' === '22'`)

Comment: True, i forgot how to javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
function max() {
   return Math.max(Number(monday.value) + Number(tuesday.value) + Number(wednesday.value) + Number(thursday.value) + Number(friday.value) + Number(saturday.value) + Number(sunday.value));
}
```

Comment: "I would like to know how to find the highest variable **without using math.max**." - This might have been edited in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **VERY RUDIMENTARY APPROACH** of doing this.  It's good to read through and understand what's going on, then eventually put all of the hours into an array.

If you're doing beginner's homework like someone else mentioned, this is probably as far as you've gotten

```
function getHighest() {
    var hrs_monday = Number(monday.value)
    var hrs_tuesday = Number(tuesday.value)
    var hrs_wednesday = Number(wednesday.value)
    var hrs_thursday = Number(thursday.value)
    var hrs_friday = Number(friday.value)
    var hrs_saturday = Number(saturday.value)
    var hrs_sunday = Number(sunday.value);
    var most_hrs = 0;

    if(hrs_monday > most_hrs) {
        most_hrs = hrs_monday;
    } 
    if(hrs_tuesday > most_hrs) {
        most_hrs = hrs_tuesday;
    } 
    if(hrs_wednesday > most_hrs) {
        most_hrs = hrs_wednesday;
    }    
    if(hrs_thursday > most_hrs) {
        most_hrs = hrs_thursday;
    } 
    if(hrs_friday > most_hrs) {
        most_hrs = hrs_friday;
    } 
    if(hrs_saturday > most_hrs) {
        most_hrs = hrs_saturday;
    } 
    if(hrs_sunday > most_hrs) {
        most_hrs = hrs_sunday;
    } 

    alert("Most hours " + most_hrs);
}
```

A better way of doing it is to put all of your variables into an array, then iterate through the array and overwrite the `most_hrs` variable:

```
var hrs_array = [];

hrs_array.push(Number(monday.value));
hrs_array.push(Number(tuesday.value));
hrs_array.push(Number(wednesday.value));
hrs_array.push(Number(thursday.value));
hrs_array.push(Number(friday.value));
hrs_array.push(Number(saturday.value));
hrs_array.push(Number(sunday.value));

max_hrs = 0;

//Now you have all of your numbers in an array
//do this when you get the numbers, not necessarily all together

for(var i = 0; i < hrs_array.length; i++){
    if(hrs_array[i] > max_hrs) {
        max_hrs = hrs_array[i];
    }
}

alert("Maximum Hours = " + max_hrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

To meet the requirements of the exercise you could write your own version of Math.max, say `numericMax` and use it as you would Math.max (for you do devise).

You will need to familiarize yourself with the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), global properties [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity), [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), possibly the global function [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) and, of course, [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) for a desription of what it does.

So the following **example** shows how `numericMax` might be written and is intended as a reference if you have difficulty writing and getting your own version to work (if you choose this approach, of course).

```
function numericMax(){
    if( arguments.length == 0){
        return -Infinity;
    }
    for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i){
        if(typeof arguments[i] != "number"){
             arguments[i] = Number(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    var max = arguments[0];
    if(isNaN(max))
        return NaN;
    for( i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i){
        num = arguments[i];
        if( isNaN(num)){
            return NaN;
        }
        if( num > max){
            max = num;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```